# Wordpress showing no title

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a website which has 10,000 hits a day and runs on wordpress. Today, I tried posting something but it din't got posted instead it shows like the screenshot in frontview and backend. When I am trying to update it. I cannot do that and when I try deleting it I can't do that. It gives an error "Error while saving changes" when using Quick Edit.

frontend Screenshot
http://www.thinklayer.com/front.png

backend screenshot
http://www.thinklayer.com/back.png

Comment: Both Screenshots: Page not found

Comment: Sorry, it was some extension issue. Please check now.

Comment: Did you copy-paste something into your post?

Comment: No I din't copy paste. I tried saving something. But before saving it my internet went down and after this. I got this error. I tried searching this in the database but was unable to find this post.

Comment: Does posting another new post work?

Comment: Yes, after this post. I posted another post and it went live with no problems. But now, this post needs to be removed.

Comment: So, everything is ok?